# Load a JavaScript external file before the inline JavaScript after it loads

Tags: javascript

How can I load a JavaScript file before the inline JavaScript after it loads?

I have an app that uses the `data-` HTML attribute and I manipulate the data of it using an external file.

But after it directly I have a function that gets the data of `data-` attribute to use it later

How to achieve that?

`HTML`

```
<script src="dist/js/script.js"></script> // I want to load this one before the script tag below it

<script> // This gets executed before the external file. Making it impossible to get the data that I want
    const localStorageData = () => {
    const el = document.querySelector(".js-localStorageHidden").dataset.storage;
    console.log(el);
    }
</script>
```

Don't care about the `data-` whatever just tell me how to execute the external file first. I said the example above so you know what I'm going through

And when the function runs before that external file I don't get my `data-` right... I get the old one

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. Unless the script tag has `ASYNC` or `DEFER`, it's loaded synchronously, and the next script doesn't run until it has loaded.

Comment: I'm sorry @Barmar but what you say might work with 2 external sources but not in my situation. Simply because in my app it doesn't work... And I forgot to mention that I have async functions in the external source. So I think this might be the reason

Comment: Are yo uadding the `.js-localStorageHidden` element in the async code? If so, it doesn't matter if the second script waits for the first script to load, it still won't wait for the async functions to finish.

Comment: Yes! I'm adding... If possible, can you show us how to do it your way? Anyway, I have found a good solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63084377/12831576

Comment: window.onload doesn't wait for async functions.

Comment: What is my way? Scripts are executed in order, I said there's nothing to do.

Comment: I thought so, but for some unknown reason it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onload` event to trigger function after the script loaded :

Full JS version :

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function () {
    //do stuff with the script
};
script.src = "dist/js/script.js";
document.head.appendChild(script); //or something of the likes
```

HTML attribut version (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) :

```
<script src="dist/js/script.js" onload="..."></script>
```