# Check if a JavaScript file was loaded

Tags: javascript

First, this is not a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036203/check-if-javascript-file-was-loaded)... And you'll see why in a second.

I have a file that I want to reference in my `HTML`

```html
    <script src="dist/js/script.js"></script>
```

But I want to check if it was loaded or not and when it loads I want to do something with it...

I have tried using the `load` event(`addEventListener`) but for some reason (I think because I have `async` features in the external file) it doesn't work.

I'm using an inline `script` tag after the external file and this (inline `script`) block of code gets executed before the script tag above it (The external file), and I want the external file to load first before my inline `script`

How can I make it so that the inline `<script>` runs after my external file has been 100% loaded?

Comment: Did you try `window.onload` ?

Comment: My God! This magically worked! Please, make it an answer and I'm going to approve it. 

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why can't you include inline script in side the JavaScript file after executing all the functions in the JavaScript file .so it will work like you were thinking.

Comment: Because the external file is Front-end written and the inline script is written from the ``backend``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `window.onload`. This event fires after all scripts are loaded.

```
function init() {
    // your code
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: I didn't know window.onload knows about async stuff as well. I thought it was just for the DOM elements being there and that's it... But this worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Attach an function to the load event: `<script src="dist/js/script.js" onload ="SomeFunction()"></script>`

Comment: Though this might work but the community doesn't recommend using this anymore. Instead, add the event in Vanilla JavaScript. And I did use the event listener but it didn't work... See reference https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html and this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: This seems to work much better with deferred scripts than window.onload.